# Why does this addEventListener function fail?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use an object in an addEventListener function to assign multiple events at once. Why did it not work?

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

$('t').addEventListener({
    onclick: function() {
        alert('hi');
    },
    onmouseover: function() {
        alert('hey');
    }
}, true, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

`addEventListener` does not support multiple events. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: So is there any way that I CAN accomplish this?

Comment: You can, adding separated listeners

Comment: Sure - call it twice.  Or use jQuery.

Comment: You can write a function that accomplishes that. (or use jQuery's bind function, but I'm assuming you already know that, since you're trying to replicate the same functionality)